# Run .NET application on local machine without .NET Framework from local server shortcut

Tags: .net, local, server

I have a .NET application that I created using VS2012, targeting .NET framework 4.0, instaled on my local server and I would like to simply create a shortcut for it on my local machine. When I have the .NET Framework 4.0 installed on the local machine, the application runs just fine, as expected.

When I try to run this application without having .NET Framework installed on my local machine, I get the error 0xc0000135, wich is related to the .NET Framework not being installed.

My question is: is there a way to run this application on the local machine installing the .NET Framework only on my local server and not on my local machine?

Thank you

Comment: Is it an app that requires a GUI?

Comment: *..only on my local server and not on my local machine..* -- For that you have ASP.Net. It runs on the server with Framework installed. Clients (browsers) connect to it and consume HTML without needing the framework locally.

Comment: The app requires a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically no. In order to run applications written in .NET you must have the framework installed on the machine you're trying to run the application on.

Answer (score 4):

If you wait for next .NET 2015 framework it will be possible. You will be able to creat your own 'mini framework' only with those dll you realy need. I's not an answer for your question but you can read more here: [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx)